# Проблема после обновления AndroidStudio2.0

Tags: android-studio

После обновления AndroidStudio к версии 2.0 при выполнении run студия выдает такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Что с этим сделать ??? Почему не работает ??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня такое тоже иногда случается. Достаточно вручную удалить эту директорию. У меня проблема после этого не появлялась ещё долго, потом этот способ снова помог.